# how to do Laravel authentication for API when using mongodb?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I create a web app using Laravel, Vue.js and MongoDB, I do login this way,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Hash;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
           'email' => 'required|email',
           'password' => 'required|between:6,25'
        ]);

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)
             ->first();

        if($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
             // generate new api token
             $user->api_token = str_random(60);
             $user->save();

             Auth::login($user, $remember = true);

             return response()
             ->json([
                'authenticated' => true,
                'api_token' => $user->api_token,
                'user_id' => $user->_id,
                'name' => $user->name
             ]);
    }

    return response()
        ->json([
            'email' => ['Provided email and password does not match!']
        ], 422);
}
```

Now when I try to get the authenticated user from Auth::user() or $request->user() in other controllers,  I get null. I think I should use the token_api to retrieve the user from the database but I think that is not safe. however, I just start learning Laravel and Vue.js so if there is any better way I will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure but I think you are not using right  auth `guard` driver in this way the guard should be `token` please check your `auth.php` file on config folder and set like below on `guards` array

```
   'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ]
```

Check and set auth for this guard with `Auth::guard('api')->user()` and`Auth::guard('api')->login($user)`